# Unreal Engine 4: UShapeComponent gives the error 'identifier is undefined'. What can I do?

Tags: c++, game-engine, unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit

I am using Unreal 4.18 and Visual Studio 2017. Using certain class like UShapeComponent, UBoxComponent, USphereComponent gives identifier is undefined error while likes of USceneComponent, UStaticMeshComponent works just fine. What's wrong?

Here is my code:

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "MyActor.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class UNREALTUROIAL_API AMyActor : public AActor
{
GENERATED_BODY()

 public:    
// Sets default values for this actor's properties
AMyActor();

 protected:
// Called when the game starts or when spawned
virtual void BeginPlay() override;

 public:    
// Called every frame
virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;


UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    UStaticMeshComponent* PickUpMesh;

UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)

    UShapeComponent* PickUpBox;
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    USceneComponent* PickUpRoot;




};
```

Comment: quick google search shows this: https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/c-gameplay-programming/122081-ushapecomponent-not-working - You need to include `"ShapeComponent.h"`

Comment: Thanks, I solved it later :)

Answer (score 0):

enter code hereYou can try adding this include to your .h file

```c
#include <Runtime/Engine/Classes/Components/SphereComponent.h>
```